# rails 4 scope NOTNULL refactor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, refactoring, ruby-style-guide

I had to create a scope to create active jobs, but this feels a little odd and honestly it's tightly coupled to PosgresSQL:

```
  scope :active, -> { where('reviewed_at NOTNULL and paid_at NOTNULL and end_at >= ?', Date.today) }
```

Would you write this differently? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A shorter & more beautiful version will be like this:

```
scope :active, -> { where.not(reviewed_at: nil, paid_at: nil).where('end_at >= ?', Date.today) }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `where.not` in rails 4

```
scope :active, -> { where.not(reviewed_at: nil).where.not(paid_at: nil).where('end_at >= ?', Date.today) }
```